# Remove Schema Field in Mongoose Discriminator

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, discriminator

I have a BaseSchema with two discriminator that add fields and methods to the BaseSchema.

```
BaseSchema
    aSchema
    bSchema
```

Now I would like to add a third discriminator that remove some fields from the BaseSchema? Is that possibile?

Otherwise I should define a LightSchema, create a discriminator for my BaseSchema as it is now and then attach the other two discriminator, is this the best approach?

```
LightSchema
    BaseSchema
        aSchema
        bSchema
```

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1):

According to the [mongoose.model jsdoc](https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/blob/6019e2f7610d1d7c70d70db6a43c37f3f8409b77/lib/model.js#L1127) you can set `options.clone=false` to have your discriminator not inherit the base schema. You would then need to explicitly re-declare the fields you want in your discriminator.